# Facebook Instant Games Ads Won't Shown

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-instant-games

Today i submitted a new Facebook Instant Game, but can't show any ads anymore.

They fail to preload, and the error reports: "Interstitial failed to preload: The SDK version in the ad request is no longer supported for new apps. Please upgrade to one of the latest versions of the SDK".

Now, i'm already using the latest: "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.2.js"

But still, can't figure out why can't show ads anymore. Yesterday it was working... any news on the question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that everything is ok suddenly.
Facebook ads team made a mess with their internal update...